# Java method for getting width of swing object of any type?

Tags: java, swing, class, methods

I have this method for placing objects in swing. At this point it does only support buttons(or any other object that has a defined method). I need a method that can work for any object, without having to define one method per type of object (button, textarea, panel etc...)

Here is my code:

```
    // Visual Methods for placing visual objects:::
static class Layout{
    static class Button{ // buttons
            static void PlaceUnder(JButton target,JButton src){
                int x = src.getLocation().x;
                int y = src.getLocation().y + src.getSize().height+2;
                target.setLocation(x,y);
            }
    static void PlaceOver(JButton target,JButton src){
        int x = src.getLocation().x;
        int y = src.getLocation().y - target.getSize().height-2;
        target.setLocation(x,y);
        }
    } // end of buttons
}
    // done....
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Swing already has plenty of layout managers. You shouldn't try implementing one yourself unless you really, really know what you're doing. And if you knew, you would know just by reading the javadoc thet getSize() is declared in Component, that all Swing components extend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDocs for `JButton` and see what it extends from.  You should find a common ancestor for all UI components

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes, i know i am kind of re-inventing the wheel, but it is just for learning... Anyways, i like the total control of beeing able to place objects exactly where i want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `javax.swing.JComponent` (or `java.awt.Component`) base class. Every Swing component extends from these.

```
static void placeUnder(JComponent target, JComponent src) {
    int x = src.getLocation().x;
    int y = src.getLocation().y + src.getSize().height+2;
    target.setLocation(x,y);
}
```